# In the end/finally/eventually

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Is *in the end* the obvious choice here? What about *eventually* or *finally*?

A: She was sick for eight months.

B: And **in the end** there was just nothing more to do?

A: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the whole flow of this conversation is extremely odd. The question B is asking is not a question anyone would usually ask, nor would they usually start their question with “And” in this context.

Usually, phrases like “in the end” (as well as “eventually” and “finally”) are used in statements.